# NetBeans IDE - ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, netbeans, ucanaccess

Trying to use UCanAccess to open an Access database with Java but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DbAccess2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

 Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/myDB.mdb");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
       System.out.println("OK");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
       // System.out.print("Not OK");
    }
}
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at DbAccess2.main(DbAccess2.java:10)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here's what my file looks like (NetBeans)

[image: screenshot.png]

Comment: You have the UCanAccess jar file and its dependencies in a folder named `lib` under "Libraries". Normally those jar files reside in "Libraries" itself, along with the JDK. It looks you unpacked a bunch of stuff and then tried to just add the folder, but that doesn't work: you need to add the actual jar files (not the folder they live in). See the NetBeans screenshot in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/2144390) for an example.

Comment: It works now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the UCanAccess jar file and its dependencies in a folder named `lib` under "Libraries". Normally those jar files reside in "Libraries" itself, along with the JDK. It looks you unpacked a bunch of stuff and then tried to just add the folder, but that doesn't work: you need to add the actual jar files (not the folder they live in). See the NetBeans screenshot in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/2144390) for an example.